# GoogleMap with Custom Image as Icon on Specific location

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite, google-maps

How to add Custom image (means i have binary images in database with their location) to Google map in android .i have developed application which capture picture and save in database,then i populate image on list view,now i have to do while click on specific image in list view android, this image should show on Google map on specific location.
please give me some reference or idea ,how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

As per my way first you have fetch your `ImagePath`, `Location(Latitude,Longitude)` data  from `SQlite` and store into `Array` or `ArrayList` and then bind into `ListView`. Now, you have to implement `Listview OnItemClickListener()`. When you click any ListItem then fetch that Particular Item data from your `Array` or `ArrayList` using Position. Now you can Pass this data into `Another Activity` using `Intent`.

Now, in your `Map Activity` you need to implement `Custom Info Window` and inflate your custom layout and load your image into info window.

Go to this for **Custom Window** tutorial: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-custom-info-contents-for-by.html

Answer (score 1):

- I would launch a new intent and open a Google Map in a separate activity.

  - The intent should include a `LatLng` object and the image to display.
  - To display these images at specific locations in a Google Map, you will want to use the `LatLng` class to store the latitude and longitude for each spot.
- Then you will want to create a `Marker` which takes a `LatLng` object to determine its position.

  - The Marker object will use your desired image by way of the `setIcon()` method.
  - To display the image on the map, simply call the `addMarker()` method with your `Google Map` object.

[LatLng](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html)
[Marker](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
Marker newMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(newLocation)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_marker))
                            .draggable(true)
                            .title("Marker with Image"));
```

Look into the [BitmapDescriptorFactory](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory.html) class methods. For how you would like to retrieve your image. I use it from the resources.

Here newLocation is kind of LatLng.